# Как сделать резервную копию databace в DB2?

Tags: windows-7, db2, ibm, база-данных

DB2 v10.1 database on WINDOWS 7.
Подскажите как сделать резервную копию базы данной на DB2. Может есть у кого подробная инструкция?

Comment: самая подробная интсрукция на сайте ibm =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db2 BACKUP DATABASE my_db2_base ONLINE TO /database/backup COMPRESS INCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
db2 backup db sample
```

Только не могу понять как прописать путь куда делать резервную копию БД